# Flutter - PostHog giving MissingPluginException on capture()

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've just started trying to integrate [posthog_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/posthog_flutter)'s functionality with no success. [PostHog](https://posthog.com) is a package that provides user activity tracking. There are 2 functions `screen` and `capture`, but my project can't recognize them and gives the error `MissingPluginException`. The current code I took from the tutorial did not have any tweaks.

Here is my implementation so far:
[image: Source]

Here is the error log:
[image: Error]